# Extracting an interface from an array of keys of an object to perform Pick and Omit

Tags: typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm having trouble coming up with the necessary typings for the following two functions:

```js
const pick = (obj, ...names) =>
  names.reduce((ret, next) => {
    if (typeof obj[next] != 'undefined') ret[next] = obj[next];
    return ret;
  }, {});

const strip = (obj, ...names) =>
  pick(obj, ...Object.keys(obj).filter(key => !names.includes(key)));
```

I've tried something like the following:

```js
type Picker = <T extends object, U extends (keyof T)[]>(obj: T, ...names: U) =>
  Pick<U, T>;

type Stripper = <T extends object, U extends (keyof T)[]>(obj: T, ...names: U) =>
  Omit<U, T>;
```

But those types require passing a type T that extends object, not array of strings. How can I construct a type from `Array<keyof T>` to pass into `Pick` and `Omit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rephrasing the question a couple of times, it occured to me that you could create a union type from an array by using the index accessor:

```js
type Picker = <U extends object, V extends (keyof U)[]>(obj: U, ...keys: V) =>
  Pick<U, V[number]>;

type Stripper = <U extends object, V extends (keyof U)[]>(obj: U, ...keys: V) =>
  Omit<U, V[number]>;
```